# If I've cast a subclass as its superclass, and call a method that was overridden in the subclass, does it perform the overridden or original method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, casting

Consider:

`Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`, and `Dog` overrides `Animal.eat()`

```
Animal[] animals = getAllAnimals();
for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    animals[i].eat();
}
```

If `Animal.eat()` is overriden by `Dog.eat()`, which one is called when the method is called from an identifier of type `Animal` (`animals[i]`?)

Comment: I do not see any cast. Is it in the getAllAnimals()?

Comment: @SantoshK it's implicit - you don't need to explicitly cast from a subclass to its superclass when you store the former in a variable declared as the superclass.

Comment: @Alnitak I know it's implicit, the question title implied a cast so I was just wondering

Comment: @BeauGrantham : Trial and error is not a viable option when experimenting 'gray areas' in programming. This kind of operations can have an unknown behavior and differ from an implementation to another.

Comment: @halflings There is no gray area here... if you think so, you need to review Java's concept of polymorphism.

Answer (score 9):

The subclass method will be called. That's the beauty of [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: understand that c++ operates differently for non-dynamic methods. Don't' assume that what holds for java holds everywhere

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still wrapping my head around polymorphism. This is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ControlAltDel - Nice comment. C++ is indeed different (although polymorphism is pretty similar; there's a nice discussion of polymorphism in C++ [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/)). All instance methods in Java are more or less equivalent to virtual methods in C++.

Comment: As a programming language nerd, I would say that this is the beauty of dynamic dispatching. Please remember that there are other types of polymorphism in addition to the subtyping polymorphism found in OO languages.

Answer (score 2):

The subclass will be the only method call, unless the subclass calls the superclass like this:

```
class Dog {
  public eat() {
     super.eat();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
Animal a = new Dog();
a.eat();
```

will call Dog's `eat` method. But beware! If you had

```
class Animal {
  public void eat(Animal victim) { 
    System.out.println("Just ate a cute " + victim.getClass().getSimpleName()); 
  }
}
```

and you have a Cat that defines an additional method:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
  public void eat(Mouse m) { System.out.println("Grabbed a MOUSE!"); }
}
```

and then you use them:

```
Animal cat = new Cat();
Animal mouse = new Mouse();
cat.eat(mouse);
```

This will print "Just ate a cute Mouse", and not "Grabbed a MOUSE!". Why? Because polymorphism only works for the object to the left of the dot in a method invocation.

Comment: Actually, by having it so that the cat is only able to eat mice you are violating the substitution principle. According to the superclass, you should be able to pass any kind of animal to the eat method.

Comment: @missingno My cat can obviously eat any animal since it inherits from `Animal`. It tries to **additionally** specialize mouse-eating behavior, but intentionally fails to do so. (The intention is mine, not cat's :)

Answer (score 1):

It'll call the version in the subclass.

Inheritance would be pretty useless if you couldn't pass around a subclassed object cast as its superclass and not get the subclassed method!

Answer (score 0):

A [sscce](http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html)

```
/**
 * @author fpuga http://conocimientoabierto.es
 * 
 * Inheritance test for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722447/
 *
 */


public class InheritanceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animals[] = new Animal[2];
    animals[0] = new Animal();
    animals[1] = new Dog();

    for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        animals[i].eat();

        if (animals[i] instanceof Dog) {
        System.out.println("!!Its a dog instance!!");
        ((Dog) animals[i]).eat();
        }
    }

    }


    private static class Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("I'm an animal");
    }
    }

    private static class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("I'm dog");
    }
    }

}
```